# ¿Como desplegar mi sitio en hosting sin que pierda los links?

Tags: java, jsf, web, primefaces, deployment

Desplegué mi sitio Java con JSF y Primefaces en DailyRazor mediante el tomcat Manager pero queda en una carpeta detrás del contexto y no logro hacer que se vea directo desde el dominio principal www.misitio.com.

Debo utilizar www.misitio.com/contexto/faces/Front/index.xhtml
..
Usando el web.xml con el tag:

```
 <welcome-file>faces/Front/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Puedo hacer que al consultar www.misitio.com/contexto me lleve al index, pero el usuario nunca sabrá llegar a contexto!

Además, no se porque siempre tengo que usar "faces"!... sin eso no me despliega nada gráfico.

Les agradezco toda la ayuda que puedan darme.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta se divide básicamente en 2 partes:

1. ¿Cómo reemplazar la aplicación ROOT (raíz) de Tomcat?
2. ¿Cómo remuevo el prefijo `faces` de mis urls?

La primera parte la adapto de [How to change the ROOT application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/715506/1065197):

Existen tres métodos (excluyentes):

1. Primero apaga tu servidor Tomcat desde la carpeta `bin` (`sh shutdown.sh` o ejecutando shutdown.bat). Luego, borra todo el contenido de la carpeta `webapps` de Tomcat (`rm -fr *`). Luego, copia tu archivo WAR en esta carpeta y renómbralo a `ROOT.war`, y finalmente vuelve a iniciar Tomcar (`sh startup.sh` o ejecutando `startup.bat`).
2. Deja tu archivo war en `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` con su nombre original. Apaga las opciones **autoDeploy** y **deployOnStartup** en tu servidor en el archivo `server.xml`. Define un contexto (`<Context>`) en `server.xml` de manera explícita, especificamento los atributos `path` y `docBase`. Debes hacer esto porque has deshabilitado los mecanismos de auto despliegue de Tomcat, y Tomcat no desplegará más tus aplicaciones a menos que encuentre sus contextos en `server.xml`. Deberás reiniciar Tomcat para que los cambios surjan efecto.
3. Coloca tu archivo WAR fuera de la carpeta `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` (debe estar fuera para prevenir un doble despliegue). Coloca un archivo de contexto llamado `ROOT.xml` en `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/`. El único elemento en este archivo DEBE tener un atributo **docBase** apuntando a la ubicación de tu archivo WAR. El elemento `path` no debe ser puesto (se deriva del nombre del archivo `.xml`, en este caso `ROOT.xml`). Mira la [documentación para el contenedor de contextos](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) para más detalles.

[Referencia](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application_.3F)

En mi opinión, escogería la primera alternativa.

Sobre la segunda parte, revisa en tu archivo web.xml cómo has configurado el mapeo de urls para `FacesServlet`. Imagino que debes tener algo como sigue:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Existen muchos tutoriales que no explican bien esta parte. Lo mejor es cambiarlo a una forma más útil:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```